# C# Selenium pop up window access

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When I click on a textbox it opens a pop up window. In the pop up window, I need to find the account name, click on it, and return to the main window.

My code can find the pop up but is unable to access the account name.

```
string currenthandle = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;
IWebElement popup =  driver.FindElementByXPath("html/body/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/form/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/span/div/span/a/img");
PopupWindowFinder finder = new PopupWindowFinder(driver);
String popupwindowhandle = finder.Click(popup);
driver.SwitchTo().Window(popupwindowhandle);
System.Console.WriteLine(popupwindowhandle);
//enter account name 
driver.FindElementByXPath("html/body/form/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/th/a").Click();
```

Comment: add `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`   before finding account name

Comment: `.SwitchTo()` is for switching to `IFRAME`s. Have you tried removing those lines and trying it?